# How to get TeamCity to run Doxygen

Tags: teamcity, doxygen

I would like to have TeamCity run Doxygen as a build step. I have tried using a MSbuild step than runs a script which runs doxygen.exe (which works locally on my computer), and also a Command Line build step. Both results in doxygen.exe giving "Process exited with code -1073741515". The Doxyfile is in the correct location.

Comment: This is something I am also trying to find the best way of doing this right now.

Answer (score 0):

I got that issue, but in my case it because I forgot to include the libclang.dll file. Also make sure to put the path within double quotes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).